# Multiple Firebase projects | logins

Tags: firebase, firebase-cli

I have multiple customer projects with project directories in VScode that I switch between. These all use Firebase and have different Firebase (i.e. Google accounts).

Every time I switch I have to

1. `firebase logout`
2. Switch to the active Chrome window of the Google/Firebase account I wish to connect to
3. `firebase login`, which will launch auth in this Chrome instance.

Sometimes its easy to forget - is there an easy way to link a Google/Firebase accounts to a project directory so when you open that directory you are connected to that Firebase instance (without having multiple laptop profiles)? With git with can specify settings in the directory config file.

Just interested to know?

Comment: This is not something that is currently supported, but it's a feature request we've heard several times that we'd like to add to the Firebase CLI at some point.

Comment: No problem, thanks for getting back to me. Just wanted to make sure I wasn't missing anything =)

Comment: I think the best thing you can do right now is use something like VirtualBox or Hyper-V to set up multiple lightweight Linux boxes, each hosting a different Firebase project.